Do we need to serialize and Deserialize JSON object Manually in spring boot?
I am a new Java developer and working on an ERP Project. I went through the codebase of my project and found some interesting and pretty complex coding structure.
The entire application was developed on pure JPA and very little use of spring boot's own interfaces, annotations, and methods. For example, no JPARepository interface was used at all. The @Repository is a class here and they used Jackson data binding for crud operation.
For example, this is repository class looks like,
@Repository
public Response save(String empRegistration) {

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(empRegistration); // from android library
        String empReg= Def.getString(json, "empReg");
        EmpRegistration empRegistration = new EmpRegistration ();
        empRegistration = objectMapperReadValue(empReg, EmpRegistration.class);
                
                Response response = baseOnlySave(EmpRegistration); // baseOnlySave is the base save method              written in pure JPA.
                return response;
}

This is objectMapperReadValue method

default <T> T objectMapperReadValue(String content, Class<T> valueType) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                
        try {

            return objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false).readValue(content,
                    valueType);

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        // return null;
    }


What I would basically do
Public Response save (Employee emp) { empRepository.save(emp); return response;}
So, my question is, do we really need to use JSONObject and  objectMapper class to save an object while developing Enterprise application in spring boot?

That's terrible code (lol exception handling, new object mapper per save, thrown away EmpRegistration, responsibility of a repository to do json responses...) and no, you can save objects as long as they are entities, see https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa or  https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest

Do you really leave // TODO Auto-generated catch block all over your production code??

It is possible to use JSONObject and ObjectMapper for CRUD operations, tho it's generally considered a less efficient and less maintainable approach, especially in enterprise applications where abstraction, type safety, scalability, performance, and maintainability are key concerns.
You might want to reconsider the approach as using JSONObject and ObjectMapper directly for CRUD operations in a Spring Boot application is not a common practice, especially when you have access to powerful features provided by Spring Data JPA and Spring Boot's auto-configuration.
In your case, refactoring the code to use Spring Data JPA repositories and following Spring Boot's conventions would likely lead to cleaner, more efficient, and more maintainable code in the long run. However, you should carefully assess the requirements and constraints of your project before making any changes.

no but if you need to have a custom json object then you should do it in your config classes.
just use jsonformat and annotations of json in spring boot
you don't have to do anything about serialization and deserialize in spring boot.
